# java print result in english and other language

Tags: java

What I want to do is to print results in english and other language in java output. 
Is there any "easy" way to do this other than copy paste the code and just translate the output in the language I need?

I am building a game with frequent input/output from the user and I would like to have the option the questions (output) to be in more than 1 languages. The input from users is only numbers, thus there won't be any differentiation there.

One way is to copy classes with output (printf) and translate them accordingly and ask user in the beginning of the game to choose the language, but in this case every time i make change in the code, I need to make those change in both copies of the code, thus making it more difficult.
Is there any shorter and more robust way?

Comment: It's called [internationalisation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, it was really helpful and quite easy to use :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the java.text.MessageFormat class.  It lets you define template messages with placeholders for data (like scores, user names, etc.) and then to repeatedly merge those messages with data to produce the kind of Strings you're looking for.  The idea is that you'd have one set of templates for each language you want to support.